How to import and test the target function only without touching other codes in the file?
I'm trying to perform a unit test on each function of a Python file using unittest.
Assuming the file I want to test is called X.py and the file containing the testing code is Y.py.
In file X, there are some imports, some def of functions, and some executable commands.
My goal is to test each function in X.py in isolation, meaning that I want to mock all interactions with the outside, including variables used and functions called. I do not want us code in X.py that is outside of the target function to be tested and executed (because they require a certain  production environment to work and may have unwanted side effects).
However, I find it impossible to avoid actually executing those codes outside the target function when importing X.py. What can I do to fix it? Or is it impossible to test a function in X.py completely separately from other codes in it? Or do I have to mock the imported modules by modifying sys.modules?
I wrote a Python function to only copy the functions in X.py to another.py file, temp_X.py. I thought that I could get around the problem by importing temp_X.py instead. However, it ended up creating more trouble because the temp_X.py doesn't recognize some stuff that should've been imported (but was not copied to temp_X.py from X.py). I think this is probably not the professional way of unit testing.

Ideally, importing a module should not have such side effects; they should be wrapped in functions that, when called, will produce the side effects.

You can't, and also shouldn't. Importing the module is going to run all of the code defined at its top level. It seems like what you actually need is a fundamentally different approach to structuring your code, creating cohesive modules that actually can be tested in isolation.

It sounds like this .py file was not written to be unit-testable. Do you have any control of this file? Can it be restructured to allow import without these disastrous side effects?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can compile the .py file and look through its compiled objects for a code object with a given name. Following is a solution to run a single function but you could pull all of the code objects into a dictionary and create function objects bound to any number of globals dictionaries.
test.py - file to test
print("This module level code must not run")

def bad():
    print("This function must not run")

test_global = "global value"

def test_function(val):
    print("Good function", val, ":", test_global)

bad()

A simple test
import types

def get_function(filename, funcname, test_globals):
    """Get a function from a .py file, bound to the given globals"""
    source = open(filename).read()
    compiled = compile(source, "test.py", "exec")
    for obj in compiled.co_consts:
        if isinstance(obj, types.CodeType) and obj.co_name == funcname:
            return types.FunctionType(obj, test_globals)
    raise ValueError("No function found")

my_test_globals = {"test_global":"other stuff"}
func = get_function("test.py", "test_function", my_test_globals)
func("test val")


Very clever idea. I'll try it right now!
